# Error Inserting Data into SQL Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having the hardest time figuring out what is wrong with my data.  I keep getting Error ORA-00984, Column Not Allowed Here.  Column is 84, which works out to be the sex character.  The table was created with the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
  (
  FNAME VARCHAR2(15)    NOT NULL,
  MINIT CHAR,
  LNAME VARCHAR2(15)    NOT NULL,
  SSN CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  BDATE DATE,
  ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30),
  SEX CHAR,
  SALARY NUMBER(10,2),
  SUPER_SSN CHAR(9),
  DNO NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT EMPPK PRIMARY KEY (SSN) DISABLE,
  CONSTRAINT EMPSUPERFK FOREIGN KEY (SUPER_SSN) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(SSN) DISABLE
  );
```

And here is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (FNAME, MINIT, LNAME, SSN, BDATE, ADDRESS, SEX, SALARY, SUPER_SSN, DNO)
VALUES ('John', 'B', 'Smith', 123456789, '1965-02-09', '731 Fondren, Houston, TX', M, 30000, 333445555, 5);
```

I have been staring at this for the past hour or so, and cannot figure it out.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you explain Whats error?

Comment: Here is the error as it comes from SQL:  Error starting at line : 33 in command -
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (FNAME, MINIT, LNAME, SSN, BDATE, ADDRESS, SEX, SALARY, SUPER_SSN, DNO)
VALUES ('John', 'B', 'Smith', 123456789, '1965-02-09', '731 Fondren, Houston, TX', M, 30000, 333445555, 5)
Error at Command Line : 34 Column : 84
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:

Comment: Hope this work:  use M as 'M' .

Comment: `M`is a column name, `'M'` is a string literal

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution will work for you:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (FNAME, MINIT, LNAME, SSN, BDATE, ADDRESS, SEX, SALARY, SUPER_SSN, DNO)
VALUES ('John', 'B', 'Smith', '123456789', '1965-02-09', '731 Fondren, Houston, TX', 'M', 30000, '333445555', 5);
```

Comment: I've tried that.  This is the error I get:  
SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Comment: The BDATE might need a date  conversion using the `to_date` function.

Comment: I've thought about that. But the error seems to be pointing to the sex column.

Comment: while insert date use      to_date(BDATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY')  and insert date as  to_date(BDATE, '12-Jan-2014')

Answer (score 0):

In your CREATE TABLE statement you did not specify the size of sex table, the default size of CHAR is 1. That means you can insert only 1 character into sex column. Or else changes needed like

```
 SEX CHAR(6)
 MINIT CHAR('*the max size of string you want to put into this column*')
```

Note I used 6 as the char size in sexbecause the max size of string you may insert is 6( for 'female').

Comment: Well, I just altered the table to make both MINIT and SEX char(1).  That still didn't work.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm fine with SEX being 1 character.  M or F.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was two-fold.  The date format was incorrect.  Should have been 01-JAN-1965.  And the SEX (M or F), needed single quotes around them.  I guess it goes to show that you shouldn't trust the data given to you.